# How to generate unique random string in a length range using Golang?

Tags: algorithm, random, go

I want to generate unique random string in a length range. For example, I set length is 10. and every time the generated string is unique .

Comment: What have you tried so far? As-is, this question is too open-ended for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 18):

**How unique is unique?**
if Universally unique, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier
Out of a total of 128 bits, Type 4 UUIDs have 6 reserved bits (4 for the version and 2 other reserved bits), so randomly generated UUIDs have 122 random bits.

for UUID see: [Is there a method to generate a UUID with go language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130321/is-there-a-method-to-generate-a-uuid-with-go-language)

**How to display it?**  ( [Binary-to-text encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding) )
A **UUID is simply a 128-bit value**.  if you display it in Hex format it will be **32 character in length**.
if you want in 10 place, 128/10=12.8 => 13 bit per place so you need 8192 alphabet !

string in Golang encoded in UTF-8 so you may use Unicode alphabet:
Unicode has enough code points, see: [How many characters can be mapped with Unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924105/how-many-characters-can-be-mapped-with-unicode)

**conclusion**:
if you need Universally unique just use UUIDs.

and see: [How to generate a random string of a fixed length in golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22892120/how-to-generate-a-random-string-of-a-fixed-length-in-golang)

or if you need pseudo random string with length 10, you may use this (but not Universally unique):

```
package main

import "crypto/rand"
import "fmt"

func main() {
    n := 5
    b := make([]byte, n)
    if _, err := rand.Read(b); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    s := fmt.Sprintf("%X", b)
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

sample output:

```
FA8EA2FBCE
```

also see:  [Output UUID in Go as a short string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37934162/output-uuid-in-go-as-a-short-string)

and:  [Is there a method to generate a UUID with go language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130321/is-there-a-method-to-generate-a-uuid-with-go-language)

Comment: Also related / useful: [Output UUID in Go as a short string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37934162/output-uuid-in-go-as-a-short-string)