# How to cut uuid in golang?

Tags: go, uuid

In order to make semi-random slugs, I'd like to use first 8 characters of uuid. So I have

```
import (
    fmt
    "github.com/satori/go.uuid"
)

    u1 := uuid.NewV4()
    fmt.Println("u1 :", u1)

    runes := []rune(u1)
    slug := string(runes[0:7])
```

But in compile time I get this error:

> cannot convert u1 (type uuid.UUID) to type []rune

How can I fix it?

Comment: Why are you trying to convert it to `[]rune`? A UUID can only contain hex characters in it's string representation. Why not just use the `String()` method?

Comment: @JimB, I'm a go noob and that's a snippet that I found to cut string to certain length. Appreciate a complete answer with code example.

Comment: you should probably start with the basic documentation, maybe run through the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org). Cutting&pasting without knowing why rarely ends well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that package (I just looked at the source code) a UUID is an alias for `[16]byte`, so you cannot concert it to a rune array, not that you want to.

Try this:

```
s := hex.EncodeToString(u1.Bytes()[:4])
```

This will give you 8 hex digits. However, this is still a roundabout way of doing things. A v4 UUID is random except for certain bits, so if you are not using the whole UUID it is more straightforward to just generate 4 random bytes. Use the `Read()` function in `math/rand` (which must be seeded) or `crypto/rand` (which is what the UUID library uses).

```
b := make([]byte, 4)
rand.Read(b) // Doesn’t actually fail
s := hex.EncodeToString(b)
```

Comment: Which do you reckon yields more random results? `hex.EncodeToString(u1.Bytes()[:4])` or `make([]byte, 4)` ?

Comment: @Karlom: `make([]byte, 4)` isn't random, you have to put random data into it.

Comment: They are both uniformly random. However, with UUIDs you are generating extra random bits so you can throw them away. Why bother with UUIDs just to throw them away?

Comment: If you read the source of the UUID library, it's using the Go PRNG anyway. Using UUID vs. generating 4 random bytes are definitively equally random.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to convert the `UUID` to a `[]rune`. That [`UUID`](https://godoc.org/github.com/satori/go.uuid#UUID) type is stored in a binary representation as a `[16]byte`. There is a [`UUID.String()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/satori/go.uuid#UUID.String) method which you can use to convert to a string, then slice it.

```
 slug := u1.String()[:7]
```

Comment: Note that this will contain dashes if you ask for more than 8 characters.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: true, but since they were specifically slicing a UUID, which the string format is part of the specification, I assumed that was intended. Otherwise why use a UUID at all.

Comment: @DietrichEpp, oh I see, they only wanted it for "randomness"

Comment: @JimB Shouldn't it be `u1.String()[:8]`, as the "hi" part of the slice is exclusive, so the current version only returns an id with length 7?

Comment: @TillKuhn: probably -- I just copied the 7 from the original; if you want 8, then you should use 8.